# Netbeans + GIT + SVN in a project?

Tags: git, svn, netbeans, project

Could be used SVN and GIT repository at the same time in one Netbeans project?
I was testing it, but no solutions found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SVN and GIT should be able to live side by side. You'll need to integrate git *into* SVN though.

First, edit *svn-ignore* to ignore *.git* and *.gitignore* files.
Add and commit. Then, you can initialize your git repo and add you full remote project:

```
git init
git remote add -f origin https://github.com/yourUserName/your-project.git
```

If you run git status now, it won't show correct git tracking. So just do :

```
git checkout -f master
```

Run again git status, you now see a lot of *.svn* files. You just need to edit *.gitignore* to ignore those.

Git is now integrated into SVN and they happily ignore each other!